# only return the group key where no row of the group is matching

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

```
| target | start | end  |
| ------ | ----- | ---- |
| 1      | NULL  | NULL |
| 1      | 100   | NULL |
| 2      | NULL  | NULL |
| 2      | NULL  | 100  |
```

I am trying to run a query over the described table, which gives me all `target` values where all  of the connected row does not match `start IS NOT NULL and end IS NULL`

**So the expected return would be**

```
| target |
| ------ |
| 2      | <-- Has no connected rows where start IS NOT NULL and end IS NULL
```

I have already tried a self join, which did not accomplish the wanted result

Comment: Could you post the request you tried too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT target
FROM tablename
GROUP BY target
HAVING SUM(start IS NOT NULL AND end IS NULL) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d7ffe5eabfb5b0e6357c8af396f2c15).